# How to model the consequences of HTTP DELETE action without actually doing it

Tags: rest, http, api-design

For an HTTP API design I need to allow the user the ability to obtain a list of changes that the HTTP DELETE call on a resource could trigger. i.e. if the resource is a parent in an one to many relationship I would need to reply with the child list.
The idea behind this is that the client could use this information to confirm destructive changes before actually making them.

So if actual action would be a simple
`HTTP DELETE /resources/uuid`

Would 
`HTTP DELETE /resources/uuid?simulate=true`

be acceptable, what would be an appropriate http status code in this case ?

I am interested to know what is the best approach for this scenario of DELETE in two steps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there's a problem with the approach. One thing that you could consider is when you have multiple APIs that need to be "simulated", it might be worth thinking about a general approach.

You could potentially have something like

```
DELETE /dryRun/resources/uuid
```

OR

```
DELETE /resources/uuid/dryRun
```

The advantage of having it as a path parameter instead of a query parameter is separation of concerns. You will avoid having `if-else` in your code with this approach.

Comment: To clients in a REST architecture the form of the URI is not of relevance as it wont interpret URIs but its accompanying link-relation name. A server may inform a client about each valid option which may include a link relation name like `dryRun` whose accompanying URI either points to the actual resource but includes a query/matrix/whatever parameter or points to a special resource that is only used for performing dry-runs and just checks whether the request is feasible